# Database transaction integrity and atomicity

Tags: database, concurrency, transactions, integrity

Assume that I create a table in an RDBMS database and create an integer field in it. Now I have two clients simultaneously change that integer field value for the same record, say client C1 sets it to 1 and at the same time client C2 sets it to 2 for the same record R1.

1. What value does the field get set to? How is this affected by each of C1 and C2 setting this value within a transaction?
2. If both C1 and C2 set the value within a transaction, does the commit succeed for both of them?

(Do the answers to questions 1 and 2 depend upon the RDBMS or is there a convention about how the system will behave?)

Answer (score 0):

The commit of a transaction can either succeed or fail. In the case of two parallel transactions writing to the same field, only one will succeed in your case.

However, depending on RDBMS, the transactions could say "increase with 1" instead of "set to 1" and in this case there is no collision and both transactions can proceed.

Comment: Only one succeeding is dependent on each RDBMS? Or do all RDBMS fail one randomly?

Comment: Read the documentation of the RDBMS under consideration.